# django_tables2 How to rezise table and also rezise bottom border

Tags: css, django-tables2

I have followed https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/tutorial.html to create a table. I have managed to rezise the table:

- python version: 3.5.2
- django version: 1.11.2

tables.py:

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from .models import Person

class PersonTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        attrs = {'class': 'paleblue','width':'300%'}


people.html:

{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% load static %}

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'django_tables2/them/paleblue/css/screen.css' %}" />
    </head>
    <body>
       {% render_table table %}

    </body>
</html>
```

I cannot see any option to change the size of bottom border in the docs ? 
Alternatively I have tried to change screen.css to remove the borders, but changes has no effect. The link is active when I click view page source even if I rename screen.css.

Comment: This isn't really a django-tables2 question but rather how to use CSS to style tables and pagination, but I'll try to answer anyway

Answer (score 0):

You should resize the container around the table and the pagination, which for the [default template has class `table-container`](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/blob/master/django_tables2/templates/django_tables2/table.html#L4).

You should use some CSS to make that container wider, something like

```
<style>
    .table-container {
        width: 300%;
    }
</style>
```

You should remove the width attribute from the table definition, as it will make the table 3 times as wide as the container.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Problem was that the link /static/django_tables2/themes/paleblue/css/screen.css can refer to two locations of screen.css. I was editing the wrong file.